# Passing a class (or struct) conforming to a Protocol to a function taking a generic type as parameter

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

**Context :**

1 - A **SQLObject** protocol declares various functions.
( I use FMDB for db access )

```
protocol SQLObject {
    static var tableName: String { get}
    init(result: FMResultSet) throws
    ...
}
```

2 - Some structs conforming to the **SQLObject** protocol, implementing the required functions

```
struct Foo : SQLObject {

    // All protocol functions implemented - No red, no yellow here :)

}
```

3 - A global data manager is defined in my app to awake objects from database

```
class DataManager {
    static let shared = DataManager()

    func storedObjects<T: SQLObject>(_ type: T) throws -> [T] {

        // This basically does a SELECT * and returns objects of the given type
        // This is also error and warning free

    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I want to deserialise my objects from anywhere in the app

```
let foos = try DataManager.shared.storedObjects(Foo)
```

When I build I got an error :

> Argument type '(Foo).Type' does not conform to expected type
>   'SQLObject'

There is something I miss here, since Foo implements the SQLObject protocol. Any explanation, coding mates?

Comment: Change `_ type: T` to `_ type: T.Type`

Comment: @Alexander is right. and call `DataManager.shared.storedObjects(Foo.self)`

Comment: Thanks @Fyodor - It looks like it works even without the self

Comment: @Fyodor but you fix a warning ;)

Comment: @matt - maybe trivially solved, but I had to ask it because I could not find any answer.. I will remove it if it does not get any vote in few time. What do you think?